# keep tabs after .split()

Tags: python

I'm working on a small project and I encountered a problem.

I'm reading a file something like this *(note, the original file has around 40k rows*):

```
35   IMAGE:1679942   SAMD4   Sterile alpha motif domain   Hs.98259   ATI146610
36   IMAGE:1700154            AI049531
37   IMAGE:1865232            AI269361
```

As you can see, there are some cells, which are containing information, and some not.
So I want that in every cell, where no information is stored, an **N/A**. How can I do this?
.split() does make a list without these cells. Is there a solution, how can I keep all these taps in a list i.e. `line = ["36", "IMAGE:1700154", "", "", "", "AI049531", ...]`

Comment: Are the columns aligned? How are the "cells" defined?

Comment: it's an .txt file and there is no cell definition
maybe this helps:
35\tIMAGE:1679942\tSAMD4\tSterile alpha motif domain\tHs.98259\tATI146610
36\tIMAGE:1700154\t\t\tAI049531

Comment: So the columns are separated by tabs `\t`?

Comment: I would use the text import wizard in excel and save the file as a csv. Then use the csv module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) at tabs (**Edit** Using data from comment):

```
data = """35\tIMAGE:1679942\tSAMD4\tSterile alpha motif domain\tHs.98259\tATI146610
36\tIMAGE:1700154\t\t\tAI049531"""

for line in data.split("\n"):
    print line.split("\t")
```

Result:

```
['35', 'IMAGE:1679942', 'SAMD4', 'Sterile alpha motif domain', 'Hs.98259', 'ATI146610']
['36', 'IMAGE:1700154', '', '', 'AI049531']
```

Comment: this solution is for this case false, because it would look like this:
line = ["36", "IMAGE:1700154","AI049531", ...] and i need the empty spots

Comment: Thanks, thats it :) i thought i already tried it... but seems not :D thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You would have to prepare the data first before being able to import it into CSV and subsequently the list format you desire.

1) Start by finding the max number of columns you would have

2) Find a pattern for each row item. Eg. A*, Sterite*, etc. Hopefully this patterns exist to distinguish between different row items.

3) For each row, do a row.split("\t")` and match each row item against the pattern to find its correct index in the row.

4) `newRow[correct_index] = oldrow[index] and "" for others`